# android renderscript stack size too small

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I need a large data buffer within my render script root method to process some data. For example, a large float array to store temp values. For that reason I just put a large array on the stack. This works fine as long the data buffer don't gets too big

Each of my root calls need its own buffer to do the calculation. If I got it correctly the root method can run in parallel and so its not possible to allocate this buffer from java since this would be shared between all running root methods, right?

Any idea how to allocate or access a local data buffer in the root method? Or is it not possible?

The size of the available size seams to be depending on the device/Android version. Is there a way to get the stack size on the current device?

(And yes its probably possible to split the job further so that it needs less buffer space but that would change the currently running algorithm completely and I would first try to find another solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderScript doesn't support allocating memory within the script itself.  It's all managed and bound by the Java (or NDK) side.

Comment: any workarounds? For example, in java I could allocate a big chunk of memory that is big enough to hold all buffers of all root method jobs. Then a non-overlapping part of this chunk is assigned to each root job (by passing the chunk offset as another parameter) However, depending on the calculation (and in my case) that chunk would be very big since there are many root calls.

Comment: It's tough to say without seeing a concrete example, but I think you're on the right track.  The "assignment" could be implied in your code using the coordinate parameters for your root.  For example, if your `Allocation` were 1D, you could use the 'x' value to offset into the large chunk of RAM bound to the root and use that space as a scratch area.  You couldn't push an offset with each root call since it's all done behind the scenes, so you'd have to derive it like this.

Comment: Yes I already use the in parameter to tell the root function what to do. From that information I could also derive the position of the buffer... Just in case somebody is interested in the code: https://github.com/czeidler/Lablet/tree/master/src/nz/ac/auckland/lablet/microphone (fft.rs and Fourier.java)